# How to take input from a php page to a python

Tags: php, python-2.7

I have  a php page that take input from an input from two select >box.
The file is process.php. This is the code:

```
    <?php

                $option = $_POST['org1'];
                echo $option;


               $option1 = $_POST['org2'];
               echo $option1;
               exec('C:\Python27\parh\common.py $option $option1', $output);
            echo $output;
               ?>
```

Now I have to take input of `$option` and `$option1` in Python is like this

```
               common.py


            <code>
               import requests
               import sys
               sys.argv[1] 
               sys.argv[2] 

                d = {}
                with open("metabolicpathways.txt") as f:
                for line in f:
                    (key, val) = line.split('\t')
                    d[(key)] = val



                def intersect(a, b):
                 return list(set(a) & set(b))

                 pathways = requests.get('http://rest.kegg.jp/list/pathway/'+sys.argv[1])
                pathways2 = requests.get('http://rest.kegg.jp/list/pathway/'+sys.argv[2])
                hsa=[]
                bar=[]
for line in pathways.content.split('\n'):
    #print line
    pathwayid = line.split('\t')[0].replace('path:', '')
    #print 'HUMAN-->',pathwayid[3:]
    hsa.append(pathwayid[3:])

print "\n\n\n\n"    

for line2 in pathways2.content.split('\n'):
    pathwayid2 = line2.split('\t')[0].replace('path:', '')
    #print 'BACILLUS-->',pathwayid2[3:]
    bar.append(pathwayid2[3:])

hsa = filter(None, hsa) 
bar = filter(None, bar)

common=intersect(hsa,bar)
for j in common:
    if j in d.keys():
        print "Common Pathway -->",j," - ",d[j],"\n"



    </code>
```

But when I am running on **WAMP** server. I am not getting any `output.plz` help me.
I have tried a lot but I am not able to figure out where I am doing the mistake.

Comment: What do you mean by _you are not getting any output_? Are there any errors? Please elaborate.

Comment: I am not getting ouput means "I am not getting the output which is desired from python script :

Comment: print "Common Pathway -->",j," - ",d[j],"\n" . this is the output i want.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to you the full path to python because the WAMP server dont know it:

```
$python = 'C:\\Python27\\python.exe'; // depend on your system so check it and replace the path if need to
exec($python.' C:\Python27\parh\common.py $option $option1', $output);
```

Comment: No @ron. It's still not giving output.

Comment: I am trying to make at php page what execute a python program. The python progra me return  an array. Now i want to ask how how does a php page take input a array from a python. Boz in output only "array" is coming?